# How to cancel individual uploads using jquery fileupload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am using [blueimp jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in a Rails 3.2 app, via the [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem, to upload multiple image files.

I am displaying 'cancel' buttons within the upload-template. These buttons successfully cancel their respective file upload. However, they also reload the page, and in doing so cancel all other simultaneous file uploads (and providing poor UX).

My javascript knowledge is limited, and I'm struggling with the documentation. What is the correct way to implement cancel buttons for single uploads when using jquery fileupload to upload multiple files.

```
    #Coffeescript

    jQuery ->
      if $("#new_asset").length
        $("#new_asset").fileupload 
          dataType: "script"
          add: (e, data) ->
            types = /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i
            file = data.files[0]
            if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
              node = data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
              $('#progress-container').append(data.context)
              jqXHR = data.submit()
              node.find(".cancel").click (e) ->
                e.preventDefault()
                jqXHR.abort()
            else
              alert("#{file.name} is not a jpeg or png image file")
          progress: (e, data) ->
            if data.context
              progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
              data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
          stop: (e, data) ->
            $('.upload').hide()

# view 
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">  
  <tr class="upload">
    <td class="preview-cell">{%=o.preview%}</td>
    <td class="name-cell">{%=o.name%}</td>
    <td class="progress-cell"><div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%;"></div></div></td>
    <td class="cancel-cell"><div class="cancel"><button class="btn info" remote="true"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button></div></td>
  </tr>
</script>

#application.js
    //= require jquery-fileupload
```

Comment: Did you hide cancel button that comes with plugin for each upload?

Comment: if you want to delete the file from ui just use $('.upload').remove;